# SearchView Filter Recyclerview

Tags: filter, android-recyclerview, searchview

251 / 5.000
Resultados de traducción
Resultado de traducción
Hello everyone, I would need to put a searchview that filters the data from my recyclerview to my project, but I have tried many options and none of them work.

I leave my ActivityMain and my CustomAdapter to see if they can solve it, Thank you very much

**MainActivity:**

```
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MyDatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase database;

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    FloatingActionButton add_button;
    FloatingActionButton home_button;
    ImageView empty_imageview;
    TextView no_data;


    private MyDatabaseHelper myDB;
    private ArrayList<String> book_id, book_titular, book_fecha, book_serie, book_accesorios, book_homologacion,book_fabricante, book_gas, book_capacidad, book_pesoorig, book_prescar, book_presprueb, book_fechafab, book_fechaulti,
            book_diametro, book_rosca, book_estadoext, book_material, book_estadoint, book_inspvis, book_insper, book_otrostrab, book_limpint, book_dictamen, book_observaciones;
    private CustomAdapter customAdapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        // Inicializar el objeto DatabaseHelper
        databaseHelper = new MyDatabaseHelper(this);

        // Copiar la base de datos desde assets si aún no existe
        databaseHelper.copyDatabaseFromAssets();

        // Abrir la base de datos para lectura
        database = databaseHelper.openDatabaseForReading();

        // Realizar operaciones de lectura en la base de datos

        // Cerrar la base de datos cuando ya no se necesite
        database.close();




        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        add_button = findViewById(R.id.add_button);
        home_button = findViewById(R.id.home_button);
        empty_imageview = findViewById(R.id.empty_imageview);
        no_data = findViewById(R.id.no_data);
        home_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {



            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainIni.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();

            }
        });
        add_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        myDB = new MyDatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
        book_id = new ArrayList<>();
        book_titular = new ArrayList<>();
        book_fecha = new ArrayList<>();
        book_serie = new ArrayList<>();
        book_accesorios = new ArrayList<>();
        book_homologacion = new ArrayList<>();
        book_fabricante = new ArrayList<>();
        book_gas = new ArrayList<>();
        book_capacidad = new ArrayList<>();
        book_pesoorig = new ArrayList<>();
        book_prescar = new ArrayList<>();
        book_presprueb = new ArrayList<>();
        book_fechafab = new ArrayList<>();
        book_fechaulti = new ArrayList<>();
        book_diametro = new ArrayList<>();
        book_rosca = new ArrayList<>();
        book_estadoext = new ArrayList<>();
        book_material = new ArrayList<>();
        book_estadoint = new ArrayList<>();
        book_inspvis = new ArrayList<>();
        book_insper = new ArrayList<>();
        book_otrostrab = new ArrayList<>();
        book_limpint = new ArrayList<>();
        book_dictamen = new ArrayList<>();
        book_observaciones = new ArrayList<>();




        storeDataInArrays();

        customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this,this, book_id, book_titular, book_fecha,
                book_serie, book_accesorios, book_homologacion, book_fabricante, book_gas, book_capacidad, book_pesoorig, book_prescar, book_presprueb, book_fechafab, book_fechaulti,
                book_diametro, book_rosca, book_estadoext, book_material, book_estadoint, book_inspvis, book_insper, book_otrostrab, book_limpint, book_dictamen, book_observaciones);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == 1){
            recreate();
        }
    }

    void storeDataInArrays(){
        Cursor cursor = myDB.readAllData();
        if(cursor.getCount() == 0){
            empty_imageview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            no_data.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            while (cursor.moveToNext()){
                book_id.add(cursor.getString(0));
                book_titular.add(cursor.getString(1));
                book_fecha.add(cursor.getString(2));
                book_serie.add(cursor.getString(3));
                book_accesorios.add(cursor.getString(4));
                book_homologacion.add(cursor.getString(5));
                book_fabricante.add(cursor.getString(6));
                book_gas.add(cursor.getString(7));
                book_capacidad.add(cursor.getString(8));
                book_pesoorig.add(cursor.getString(9));
                book_prescar.add(cursor.getString(10));
                book_presprueb.add(cursor.getString(11));
                book_fechafab.add(cursor.getString(12));
                book_fechaulti.add(cursor.getString(13));
                book_diametro.add(cursor.getString(14));
                book_rosca.add(cursor.getString(15));
                book_estadoext.add(cursor.getString(16));
                book_material.add(cursor.getString(17));
                book_estadoint.add(cursor.getString(18));
                book_inspvis.add(cursor.getString(19));
                book_insper.add(cursor.getString(20));
                book_otrostrab.add(cursor.getString(21));
                book_limpint.add(cursor.getString(22));
                book_dictamen.add(cursor.getString(23));
                book_observaciones.add(cursor.getString(24));

            }
            empty_imageview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            no_data.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.delete_all){
            confirmDialog();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    void confirmDialog(){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Eliminar todos los registros?");
        builder.setMessage("Está seguro que desea eliminar todos los registros?");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Si", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                MyDatabaseHelper myDB = new MyDatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                myDB.deleteAllData();
                //Refresh Activity
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

            }
        });
        builder.create().show();
    }
}
```

**Y este mi CustomAdapter:**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList book_id, book_titular, book_fecha, book_serie, book_accesorios, book_homologacion ,book_fabricante, book_gas, book_capacidad, book_pesoorig, book_prescar,
            book_presprueb, book_fechafab, book_fechaulti, book_diametro, book_rosca, book_estadoext, book_material, book_estadoint, book_inspvis, book_insper, book_otrostrab,
            book_limpint, book_dictamen, book_observaciones;

    CustomAdapter(Activity activity, Context context, ArrayList book_id, ArrayList book_titular, ArrayList book_fecha,
                  ArrayList book_serie, ArrayList book_accesorios, ArrayList book_homologacion, ArrayList book_fabricante, ArrayList<String> book_gas, ArrayList<String> book_capacidad,
                  ArrayList<String> book_pesoorig, ArrayList<String> book_prescar, ArrayList<String> book_presprueb, ArrayList<String> book_fechafab, ArrayList<String> book_fechaulti,
                  ArrayList<String> book_diametro, ArrayList<String> book_rosca, ArrayList<String> book_estadoext, ArrayList<String> book_material, ArrayList<String> book_estadoint,
                  ArrayList<String> book_inspvis, ArrayList<String> book_insper, ArrayList<String> book_otrostrab, ArrayList<String> book_limpint, ArrayList<String> book_dictamen,
                  ArrayList<String> book_observaciones){
        this.activity = activity;
        this.context = context;
        this.book_id = book_id;
        this.book_titular = book_titular;
        this.book_fecha = book_fecha;
        this.book_serie = book_serie;
        this.book_accesorios = book_accesorios;
        this.book_homologacion = book_homologacion;
        this.book_fabricante = book_fabricante;
        this.book_gas = book_gas;
        this.book_capacidad = book_capacidad;
        this.book_pesoorig = book_pesoorig;
        this.book_prescar = book_prescar;
        this.book_presprueb = book_presprueb;
        this.book_fechafab = book_fechafab;
        this.book_fechaulti = book_fechaulti;
        this.book_diametro = book_diametro;
        this.book_rosca = book_rosca;
        this.book_estadoext = book_estadoext;
        this.book_material = book_material;
        this.book_estadoint = book_estadoint;
        this.book_inspvis = book_inspvis;
        this.book_insper = book_insper;
        this.book_otrostrab = book_otrostrab;
        this.book_limpint = book_limpint;
        this.book_dictamen = book_dictamen;
        this.book_observaciones = book_observaciones;

    }




    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_row, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.book_id_txt.setText(String.valueOf(book_id.get(position)));
        holder.book_titular_txt.setText(String.valueOf(book_titular.get(position)));
        holder.book_fecha_txt.setText(String.valueOf(book_fecha.get(position)));
        holder.book_serie_txt.setText(String.valueOf(book_serie.get(position)));
        holder.book_accesorios_txt.setText(String.valueOf(book_accesorios.get(position)));
        holder.book_homologacion_txt.setText(String.valueOf(book_homologacion.get(position)));
        holder.book_fabricante_txt.setText(String.valueOf(book_fabricante.get(position)));
        holder.book_gas_txt.setText(String.valueOf(book_gas.get(position)));
        holder.book_capacidad_txt.setText(String.valueOf(book_capacidad.get(position)));
        holder.book_pesoorig_txt.setText(String.valueOf(book_pesoorig.get(position)));
        holder.book_prescar_txt.setText(String.valueOf(book_prescar.get(position)));
        holder.book_presprueb_txt.setText(String.valueOf(book_presprueb.get(position)));
        holder.book_fechafab_txt.setText(String.valueOf(book_fechafab.get(position)));
        holder.book_fechaulti_txt.setText(String.valueOf(book_fechaulti.get(position)));
        holder.book_diametro_txt.setText(String.valueOf(book_diametro.get(position)));
        holder.book_rosca_txt.setText(String.valueOf(book_rosca.get(position)));
        holder.book_estadoext_txt.setText(String.valueOf(book_estadoext.get(position)));
        holder.book_material_txt.setText(String.valueOf(book_material.get(position)));
        holder.book_estadoint_txt.setText(String.valueOf(book_estadoint.get(position)));
        holder.book_inspvis_txt.setText(String.valueOf(book_inspvis.get(position)));
        holder.book_insper_txt.setText(String.valueOf(book_insper.get(position)));
        holder.book_otrostrab_txt.setText(String.valueOf(book_otrostrab.get(position)));
        holder.book_limpint_txt.setText(String.valueOf(book_limpint.get(position)));
        holder.book_dictamen_txt.setText(String.valueOf(book_dictamen.get(position)));
        holder.book_observaciones_txt.setText(String.valueOf(book_observaciones.get(position)));

        //Recyclerview onClickListener
        holder.mainLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, UpdateActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("id", String.valueOf(book_id.get(position)));
                intent.putExtra("titular", String.valueOf(book_titular.get(position)));
                intent.putExtra("fecha", String.valueOf(book_fecha.get(position)));
                intent.putExtra("serie", String.valueOf(book_serie.get(position)));
                intent.putExtra("accesorios", String.valueOf(book_accesorios.get(position)));
                intent.putExtra("homologacion", String.valueOf(book_homologacion.get(position)));
                intent.putExtra("fabricante", String.valueOf(book_fabricante.get(position)));
                intent.putExtra("gas", String.valueOf(book_gas.get(position)));
                intent.putExtra("capacidad", String.valueOf(book_capacidad.get(position)));
                intent.putExtra("pesoorig", String.valueOf(book_pesoorig.get(position)));
                intent.putExtra("prescar", String.valueOf(book_prescar.get(position)));
                intent.putExtra("presprueb", String.valueOf(book_presprueb.get(position)));
                intent.putExtra("fechafab", String.valueOf(book_fechafab.get(position)));
                intent.putExtra("fechaulti", String.valueOf(book_fechaulti.get(position)));
                intent.putExtra("diametro", String.valueOf(book_diametro.get(position)));
                intent.putExtra("rosca", String.valueOf(book_rosca.get(position)));
                intent.putExtra("estadoext", String.valueOf(book_estadoext.get(position)));
                intent.putExtra("material", String.valueOf(book_material.get(position)));
                intent.putExtra("estadoint", String.valueOf(book_estadoint.get(position)));
                intent.putExtra("inspvis", String.valueOf(book_inspvis.get(position)));
                intent.putExtra("insper", String.valueOf(book_insper.get(position)));
                intent.putExtra("otrostrab", String.valueOf(book_otrostrab.get(position)));
                intent.putExtra("limpint", String.valueOf(book_limpint.get(position)));
                intent.putExtra("dictamen", String.valueOf(book_dictamen.get(position)));
                intent.putExtra("observaciones", String.valueOf(book_observaciones.get(position)));
                activity.startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            }
        });


    }



    public int getItemCount() {
        return book_id.size();
    }



    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView book_id_txt, book_titular_txt, book_fecha_txt, book_serie_txt, book_accesorios_txt, book_homologacion_txt, book_fabricante_txt, book_gas_txt, book_capacidad_txt
                , book_pesoorig_txt, book_prescar_txt, book_presprueb_txt, book_fechafab_txt, book_fechaulti_txt, book_diametro_txt, book_rosca_txt, book_estadoext_txt, book_material_txt, book_estadoint_txt, book_inspvis_txt
                , book_insper_txt, book_otrostrab_txt, book_limpint_txt, book_dictamen_txt, book_observaciones_txt;
        LinearLayout mainLayout;

        MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            book_id_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.book_id_txt);
            book_titular_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.book_titular_txt);
            book_fecha_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.book_fecha_txt);
            book_serie_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.book_serie_txt);
            book_accesorios_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.book_accesorios_txt);
            book_homologacion_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.book_homologacion_txt);
            book_fabricante_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.book_fabricante_txt);
            book_gas_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.book_gas_txt);
            book_capacidad_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.book_capacidad_txt);
            book_pesoorig_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.book_pesoorig_txt);
            book_prescar_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.book_prescar_txt);
            book_presprueb_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.book_presprueb_txt);
            book_fechafab_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.book_fechafab_txt);
            book_fechaulti_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.book_fechaulti_txt);
            book_diametro_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.book_diametro_txt);
            book_rosca_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.book_rosca_txt);
            book_estadoext_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.book_estadoext_txt);
            book_material_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.book_material_txt);
            book_estadoint_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.book_estadoint_txt);
            book_inspvis_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.book_inspvis_txt);
            book_insper_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.book_insper_txt);
            book_otrostrab_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.book_otrostrab_txt);
            book_limpint_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.book_limpint_txt);
            book_dictamen_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.book_dictamen_txt);
            book_observaciones_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.book_observaciones_txt);

            mainLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
            //Animate Recyclerview
            Animation translate_anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.translate_anim);
            mainLayout.setAnimation(translate_anim);
        }

    }

}
```